# jquery click() not working in ie7 and ie8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

Can some one help to solve this:

```
$('#cont2, #cont3').hide();
$('li a').click(function(){
    var idx= $(this).attr('id').substr(-1);
    $('#cont1, #cont2, #cont3').hide();
    $('#cont'+idx).show();
    return false;
});
```

This is not working in IE7 and IE8. Why?

HTML

```
<ul>
       <li class="linktab"><a href="#" id="link1">Link1</a></li>
       <li class="linktab"><a href="#" id="link2">Link2</a></li>
       <li class="linktab"><a href="#" id="link3">Link3</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="cont1">content 1</div>
<div id="cont2">content 2</div>
<div id="cont3">content 3</div>
```

Comment: What version of jQuery do you use (live being removed from new ones) ? What happens or fails to happen ?

Comment: You may also want to consider proper implementation of jQuery's `preventDefault()` to also block the default behavior of clicking the anchor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because old IE's `substr` implementation [does not support a negative index as the argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr). There is a drop-in replacement in that MDN page, or you can simply do

```
var id = $(this).attr('id');
var idx= id.substr(id.length - 2);
```

Comment: small change: var idx= id.substr(id.length - 1);